# Kentico claim based authentication with windows authenticaion

Tags: authentication, claims-based-identity, kentico

I am developing kentico application and i need to used windows authentication or claim based authentication depend on the user. If the user is Active directory user user should be able to login using username and password. If the user is not a Active directory user, user redirect to third party site for claim based authentication.

I wonder it is possible to implement this requirement with Kentico 9 CMS. If possible what is the best approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Kentico documentation claims based authentication with AD would work out of the box with just proper settings.

You can start on the following page and links over there should connect you t configuration as well:

https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Claims-based+authentication

Answer (score 0):

Aproach Michal suggested would work for third party authentication.

Here is how you can implement AD authentication (quite easy): https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Configuring+mixed-mode+authentication

Unfortunately I'm not sure you can mix them together.

Authentication.Execute custom event handler might be a right place to inject your custom implementation for it.